# How to create XmlElement with no value with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xmlelement

Would like to create the following XML element using JAXB, no value(content), no closing element name, just closing '/' :

```
 <ElementName attribute1="A" attribute2="B"" xsi:type="type" xmlns="some_namespace"/>
```

Trying the following

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)                                  

public class ElementName {
@XmlElement(name = "ElementName", nillable = true)
protected String value;
@XmlAttribute(name = "attribute1")
protected String attribute1;
@XmlAttribute(name = "attribute2")
protected String attribute2;
}
```

When constructing an object of this type as below, there is an exception

```
ElementName element = new ElementName();
```

What is the correct way of doing it ?

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to achieve it for `ElementName` with `value` set to `null` remove `nillable` attribute. Simple example how to generate `XML` payload:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

public class JaxbApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ElementName.class);

        ElementName en = new ElementName();
        en.attribute1 = "A";
        en.attribute2 = "B";
        en.value = null;

        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(en, System.out);
    }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "ElementName")
class ElementName {

    @XmlElement(name = "ElementName")
    protected String value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "attribute1")
    protected String attribute1;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "attribute2")
    protected String attribute2;
}
```

prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ElementName attribute1="A" attribute2="B"/>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. In addtion , how do i define the type and namespace for this xmlElement ?

Comment: @uriBaba, For adding `xmlns="some_namespace"` use `@XmlRootElement` `namespace` attribute.  For  `xsi:type="type"` you should add new property `private String type = "type"` with `@XmlAttribute(name = "xsi:type")` annotation. I did not test it but it should work.

Comment: Thanks. if i want to add this element as a child element for example -                                 <Parent>                                                                                      
<ElementName attribute1="A" attribute2="B"" xsi:type="type" xmlns="some_namespace"/> </Parent>                                                                                How should it be done ?

Comment: @uriBaba, You need to create new class `Parent` and wrap ElementName.